# Jquery Visitor notify box

Tags: java, php, css, notify

I am looking to create a Slide up box, how I would want this to work is when someone visits the site a small box would popup in the right corner of the site that has text in it which could say hey register to the site or just informer the visitor of some information that is going on.

I would want this to be free to customize like css wise so this box can fit the site look, if anyone know about any guides or have the code it would be really helpful.

I tried googling it but could not find what I was really looking for, since most of them only pop-up when you click a button, I want this to slide up automatically and have a x button which allows the person to make the box disappear, and I would want one that just lets it show/hide.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at this:

http://ned.im/noty/

It may be what you're looking for!

You can customize it to your liking too :)

Comment: It is something like that when you load the site at the top it shows a notify. I would like something like that but at the bottom corner, but honestly this site is really confusing on the code part.